# Take IP Addresses only from log file and save to File, Table, or .CSV

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, regex, csv

Take IP Addresses only from log file and save to File, Table, or .CSV

I have a log file with entries like so:

```
2010-09-13 00:00:01 69.143.116.98 - W3SVC2 STREAM 209.22.66.152 80 GET /p7pm/p7popmenu.js - 200 0 7700 379 188 .org Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.0;+WOW64;+GoogleT5;+SLCC1;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+Media+Center+PC+5.0;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30618;+.NET4.0C) - .org/
Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+Yahoo!+Slurp/3.0;+.com) - waste.html
2010-09-13 08:52:15 67.195.112.157 - W3SVC2 STREAM 209.22.66.152 80 GET /includes/Center_nav_p4.css - 304 0 164 482 0 HTTP/1.0 LOL.org Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+Yahoo!+Slurp/3.0;+.com) - waste.html
```

What I am thinking is the best way to extract the IP address of each log entry and save that as a line or row in a database. I would probably save into a List first or something like that and then into a db, csv, or text file with just the ip addreses.

Something like this:

```
"69.143.116.98" 
"65.37.53.228" 
"169.123.16.100" 
"169.123.16.12" 
"169.123.16.9" 
"169.123.6.89"
```

It looks like the IP address begins on the 21st line so was thinking I can somehow start there but then to figure out how to get the rest of the IP.
maybe something like start at the 21st and then grab all until I hit a space?

After I grab them all I will then count and sort them and save them to the final format.

Am I on the right path? 
Thanks.

Apparently I didn't get the whole task in here; it appears it is going to be a bit harder. It is a TON of sorting involved; I imagine the first part is grabing this data and put into some sort of table and then do al lthis sorting and finally write out the count, IP after sorting to csv........

I need to parse in this log file and here is what needs to happen; it is crazy:

1.) The code will count the number of requests made by the IP addresses contained in the log file.

2.) The code will only count GET requests made over the standard port used for HTTP and should exclude from the count all requests made from IP's beginning with '207.114'.

3. )The the final CSV file should be ordered so that IPs that made the most requests are listed first.
4. )IPs that made the same number of requests should be ordered amongst themselves with the IP octets of greater values listed first.
5. )The first column should contain the number of requests and the second will contain the IP address that made them. 
   SomeFromLog.csv - Example based on data below:

8, "69.143.116.98"

3, "65.37.53.228"

1, "169.123.16.100"

1, "169.123.16.12"

1, "169.123.16.9"

1, "169.123.6.89"

Comment: With tasks like this it is always important to know what format the source data is in. It looks like the log from a web server, can you tell us which web server and what logging options are set?

Comment: It is a .log file I believe from IIS where each line looks like this:

2010-08-12 08:52:58 63.160.106.254 - W3SVC111 STREAM 207.22.66.152 80 GET /includes/scripts.js - 304 0 164 456 0 HTTP/1.1 www.LOL.org Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+SV1;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727) __utma=228961600.1845892080.1265608268.1279440521.1279522956.43 http://www.LOL.org/

I am thinking that it needs to be somehow read line by line and parsed so that the entire thing ends up in a DB table so that the sorting can be done/ The question is; how to do that part?

Comment: IIS supports 3 formats out the box and plug-ins to store the log in nearly any format. However if you haven't changed any of the settings it is probably in W3C Extended Log File format (see https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-logfile.html). Note that not every line in this format is the same, some of the lines are "Directives" that describe the structure of the other lines, these start with #. Also, using configuration settings, it is possible to add or remove columns sometimes part way through a file. As such it best to use a pre-written parser. The one Yann suggests below seems a reasonable choice.

Comment: 1. The way I see this being done is to read in each line of the log file into a list<string> LogFileList = new list<string>(); of some kind.

2. Now we have the log file lines in a list, we run over that list and eliminate requests made from IP's beginning with '207.114' on the first pass.

3. Run through again and eliminate lines that aren’t a GET on port 80.

4. Now we create a second List<int,string> =LogFileResults = new List<int,string>(); or could be a List<string, string> to hold the final results.

Comment: 5. We need to take each row from the LogFileList  and check the IP address, if this is already in LogFileResults then we simply at 1 to the count for that IP, if not then this is a new IPaddress entry and we add it to the LogFileResults as another row.

6. At the end we should have a count for each IP address without any duplicated IP address in the results.

12, "64.143.116.98"
4, "65.37.53.228"
2, "166.123.16.100"
1, "166.123.16.12"


How would you go about doing this in C#?

Answer (score 2):

You can install TX.Windows from nugget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tx.Windows

`PM > Install-Package Tx.Windows`

And then use it like that:

```
        var iisLog = W3CEnumerable.FromFile(pathToLog);
        List<string> IpsLog = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in iisLog)
        {
            IpsLog.Add(item.c_ip);
        }
```

If the log file is used by another process, you can use W3CEnumerable.FromStream

Comment: How would I use this to parse the entire log file into a SQL table or something that is sortable we can work with? I edited my answer above and it appears that there will be a lot of sorting needed to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

```
string line = string.Empty;
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("path/to/file")) {
    while((line = sr.ReadLine())!=null) {
        var matches = Regex.Match(line, @"^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$");
        if(matches == null) continue;
        foreach(var group in match.Group) {
            //Do your staff here
        }
    }
}
```

Using this `Regex` you will able to match only the valid IPs and if there is nothing to match it will continue the `while` cycle (according to the `if` statement)

Comment: How would I use this to parse the entire log file into a SQL table or something that is sortable we can work with? I edited my answer above and it appears that there will be a lot of sorting needed to accomplish this. I thought about using LogParser but is there a way with code to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Add the namespace,

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Then use Regular Expression

```
  string pattern = @"\b(?:(?:2(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:(?:2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))";
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
        string input =File.ReadAllText(path) ;
        MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(input);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

This way you will get all the IP addresses in an array.
You can use regexr to check regular expressions: http://regexr.com/

Comment: How would I use this to parse the entire log file into a SQL table or something that is sortable we can work with? I edited my answer above and it appears that there will be a lot of sorting needed to accomplish this. I thought about using LogParser but is there a way with code to do the same thing?